# Get a Count and Group By in Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a table like this,

I want to get a

```
 NewsNumber Amount
   100        1555
   101        1700
```

> > Eror : ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Here i tried like this,

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM(SELECT AMOUNT
FROM TBL_NEWS_DTL
Group By NEWSNUMBER)
```

My Table 
 
  NEWSNUMBER | CODE | AMOUNT
       100                                 LX            1000
       101                                  LQ            1200
       100                                 RQ            555
      101                                 DW           500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inner select query, You don't have group by column in your selected field.

You don't need inner select too. You could do it like:

```
SELECT NEWSNUMBER, SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY NEWSNUMBER
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't even need a group by:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM TBL_NEWS_DTL
```

Or you want it per `NEWSNUMBER`

```
SELECT NEWSNUMBER,SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM TBL_NEWS_DTL
GROUP BY NEWSNUMBER
```

Oracle doesn't accept to group by a column, and not mention it in the select list.